# flare prefuse Dependency Graph error

Tags: flash-builder, prefuse, flare

I am using Flash Builder 4 to display a dependency graph.
The source code is in this location - [dependency graph sample application](http://flare.prefuse.org/src/flare.apps/src/flare/apps/DependencyGraph.as)
I get the error -

A file found in a source-path must have the same package structure '', as the definition's package, 'flare.apps'.

I have imported App.as
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The file `/src/com/example/Foo.as` should begin with `package com.example` and define the `Foo` class.  This is a common OO setup that Flash Builder requires.

Recreate the `flare/apps/App.as` directory structure in your project's `/src` folder and you'll be all set.